# Item Response Theory for Continuous-Unbounded Response

Tags: item-response-theory

I would like to model a problem using IRT, but my response is continuous and possibly infinite (e.g. score of a game).

I'm aware of Samejima's and Wang and Zeng's approach, but both attempts to bound the continuous response to [0,1]. In both models, the max is assumed to be known, but in my case, the response is the possibly unbounded.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?